# Para que serve while(0) e while(1) em C?

Tags: c, while

Qual a finalidade disso? `While(0)` ou `While(1).`
O 1 verifica que é correto e o 0 que está errado? Porquê?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Um laço continua (executa o próximo passo) se sua condição for verdadeira, e não continua se for falsa. Em C, zero é considerado "falso" e tudo o mais é considerado verdadeiro. Sendo assim:

- `while(0)` significa "nunca entre no loop". Sozinho, não faz nenhum sentido (pois seria mais fácil simplesmente não ter o loop...), mas como apontado por pmg e Renan Cavalieri, ele pode ser útil em uma construção `do...while`.

  Embora um bloco `do...while` com condição sempre falsa só vai executar uma única vez - e portanto poderia ser substituída pelo corpo do loop e só - ele pode ser útil para encapsular duas ou mais instruções em uma única macro. Veja [a resposta do pmg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104397/215) para um exemplo. A utilidade disso é que a macro pode então ser usada em qualquer lugar que espere uma instrução, sem quebrar a sintaxe nem a semântica do código. Outro exemplo seria:

  ```
  #define foo do { if ( condição ) instrução; } while(0)

  if (condition)
      foo;
  else
      bar;
  ```

  Resultando em:

  ```
  if (condition)
      do { if ( condição ) instrução; } while(0);
  else
      bar;
  ```

  <sup>[Fonte](http://www.bruceblinn.com/linuxinfo/DoWhile.html)</sup>
- `while(1)` significa "sempre entre no loop". Ou seja, toda vez que a condição for testada (no início, e sempre que um passo terminar) ela vai dar verdadeira e o loop vai continuar. Isso é essencialmente um "loop infinito", isto é, a menos que no corpo do loop exista uma instrução `break` ou `return` que faça com que o mesmo termine.

  A motivação de loops infinitos é, entre outras coisas, fazer com que um processo execute continuamente enquanto o programa está ativo, sem "data pra acabar". Um exemplo seria um console REPL (*"read-eval-print loop"*) que lê uma instrução do usuário, executa, imprime o resultado e vai pra próxima, *ad infinitum*, ou até que o usuário entre com um comando pra sair. Outro seria um servidor web, por exemplo, que espera uma requisição chegar, trata da mesma e envia a resposta pro cliente, e continua fazendo isso enquanto o servidor estiver ligado (potencialmente por dias, meses, até anos). Há ainda outros exemplos, como um tratador de eventos do SO (ouve por cliques do mouse e pressionamento de teclas do teclado), simulações, jogos, etc.

Comment: O `while(0)` normalmente é a parte final dum ciclo `do`

Comment: Eu encontrei esse link mostrando alguns exemplos de uso - http://www.bruceblinn.com/linuxinfo/DoWhile.html

Comment: +1, só que eu demorei um pouco para entender pq que o primeiro exemplo ia dar problema sem o while(0)

Answer (score 8):

O `while(1)` é normalmente usado para ciclos infinitos

```
while (1) {
    /* ciclo infinito, por exemplo */
    system("stayactive"); // mantem a aplicacao activa, mesmo que ela crashe
}
```

O `while(0)` é normalmente usado como parte final dum ciclo `do` para agrupar um número de instruções numa macro e manter a sintaxe de C no que respeita a ponto-e-virgula

```
#define XPTO do { um(); dois(); tres(); } while(0)

/* nota o ; abaixo */
XPTO;
```

Answer (score 1):

A linguagem C não possui por padrão o tipo boleano, por isso, ele usa o 1 e 0 como verdadeiroe/ou falso, como em binários, onde 1 possui tensão e 0 não possui. Sendo assim, o while - ou qualquer outro comando de condições como 0 sendo falso e 1 - ou qualquer número diferente de 0 - sendo verdadeiro.