# É uma boa prática de programação escrever um while com argumento true para que ele seja executado infinitamente?

Tags: java, while

Em uma situação hipotética:
É uma boa prática de programação, escrever um while dessa maneira? Para que ele continue sendo executado infinitamente?

```
    while(true){
    System.out.println("Por favor, Escolha: ");
    System.out.println("1: Adicionar Cliente");
    System.out.println("2: Depositar Dinheiro");
    System.out.println("3: Retirar Dinheiro");
    System.out.println("4: Checar Conta");
    System.out.println("5: Calcular Valor");
    System.out.println("6: Sair");
    }
```

Comment: Ta faltando uma leitura(entrada do usuário) ai :P

Comment: A questão é se um `while (true)` tem um caso válido ou se esse seu caso exatamente é válido?

Comment: Sim, no geral gostaria de saber se em algum momento, eu precisar fazer um while desse jeito, se é errado?

Comment: Só olhando esse código fica díficil, com a entrada do usuário e se algum dos métodos chamados pelos números matar a aplicação ou chamar o menu novamente é até razoavel

Comment: Editei a pergunta para uma situação hipotética, não tinha especificado antes. Obrigada.

Comment: Entendi, vou postar o código todo. Obrigada.

Comment: Pra essa situação ai não faz sentido, o loop vai ficar infinito sem ter nada para mudar esta condição.

Comment: Pra situação da sua pergunta, o while faria sentido se fosse `while (escolha != 6)`, por exemplo. O uso de while/do-while não fere nenhuma best practice. Você deve usá-lo sempre que querer que algo seja executado no mínimo uma vez, e não souber o número de vezes que ele deverá se repetir.

Comment: Esse é um dos casos mais típicos onde a boa prática não serve pra nada. Neste exemplo mostrado é claro que não deve fazer isto. Em outro exemplo, é o mais correto a se fazer.

Comment: Entendi gente, muito obrigada. Eu ainda estou me adaptando, tentando entender como um todo para depois quando eu precisar, eu realmente ter a certeza se vou poder utilizar ou não. ;)

Comment: Eu posso fazer o while desse modo contanto que eu tenha algum modo de que ele pare em algum momento... É porque eu nunca vi um while sendo feito com apenas (true) e fiquei na dúvida.

Comment: Como outros ja citaram acima, while(true) não é uma má prática se houver uma condição pra quebrar esse loop em algum momento, jogos por exemplo usam while(true) em uma thread para trabalhar o movimento de objetos e outras informações...

Comment: Se você conseguir evitar é melhor, pois o código fica mais difícil de ler. Não nesse seu exemplo, pois ele é bem simples, agora imagine códigos mais complexos, com algumas condições de paradas usando break dentro da repetição, se não muito bem estruturado fica difícil de dar manutenção.

Comment: Recomendo cuidado com o termo "boa prática", pois este normalmente é usado para propagar idéias "enlatadas" de quem não domina o que está fazendo, ou que não quer ter o trabalho de explicar (geralmente é o primeiro caso, vide muitos professores que nunca usaram programação pra nada sério que não fosse apenas teórico, e vendem essas receitas prontas), então eu recomendo que você não compre esta idéia quando tentarem te aplicar esta terminologia, e cobrar uma explicação mais séria. Tudo em programação tem que ter uma razão técnica pra ser feito, e "boa prática" não é uma razão verdadeira

Comment: Assunto relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104376/70

Comment: Então, não é bom usar o termo boa prática porque na programação uma boa prática seria um código bem feito? Seja ele, do jeito que você fizer...Não tem uma receita... Seria isso?